# SideBar Longer Then Content (CSS issue) & Making images Look Better

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need your assistance with our Blog page. First, we've had issues with our developer firm and stopped working with them. I'm with the marketing team and trying to fix things with limited knowledge.

I've built a Blog page using a Plugin and CSS; the problem is that our SideBar is slightly longer (in terms of height) than the content itself. How can I fix this?

Page Link: https://www.mgc.com.tr/hukuki-icerikler/

CSS File: https://www.mgc.com.tr/wp-content/themes/CrabsMedia/lib/css/e-hukuk-css.css

My other question is, how can I make these images look better?

Thanks,

Kind regards.

P.S. Website is WordPress.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***For your first question:***

As per your CSS and respective class `.leftsidebarcontent`, you have set its width to 20% of the parent width.

You can reduce the width as per your requirement. Its easy.

```
.leftsidebarcontent {
  width: 15%;/* <--- Increase or Decrease this width as much as you want. */
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
}
```

***For your second question:***

You have set the width of the images in `%`, you can change the value of the parent element to reduce like below

```
@media (min-width: 640px)
.blog-card .meta {
  flex-basis: 30%;/* <----- Change this value to 30% */
  height: auto;
}
```

As you have responsive CSS, you have to change all `flex-basis` values of `.block-card .meta` in your CSS.

Change the value and check in all screens whether the images is skewed or not.

If you find images are still skewed, then change again until it fits/looks proportionate.

Comment: Hello! First, thanks for your answer. For the first question, I'm talking about height, not weight. I'll play around with the second answer and reply back here.

Comment: %30 worked like a wonder, thank you!

Comment: @gfo95 I have checked your website, nothing problem with the height of the sidebar. it looks perfect. I personally feel, without that border, the whole empty space will look horrible to any website.